# SIC Assembler I/O

Tags: c, assembly

I've coded a SIC assembler and everything seems to be working fine except for the I/O aspect of it.

I've  loaded the object code into memory (converted char format into machine representation), but when I call SICRun(); to execute the code, I get an error stating "devf1 cannot be found".

I know this is related to the input/output device instructions in the source code.

The c file states that it depends on external files, most notably, Dev[6]. Am I supposed to create this myself? My instructor did not give us any other files to work with. Any insight?

Example: TD OUTPUT ;TEST OUTPUT DEVICE

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20100221225221/http://cs.panam.edu/~egle/CSCI3334/) directory contains the source code (source.asm), header file (sic.h) and the SIC simulator (sicengine.c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `sicengine.c` source file it looks as though the `devf1` (also `dev2`/`dev3`) file is expected to exist so this 'input device' can be read from (`fopen` is passed `"r"` as a parameter):

```
if (opcode == 216) {  /* RD */
    /* ... */
    if ((Dev[Devcode] = fopen(SICFile[Devcode],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file %s\n", SICFile[Devcode]);
        exit(1);
    }
```

The comment in the code about depending on file `Dev[6]` is ambiguous. It really means the names of the files in the `Dev` array, which are `devf1`, `devf2` and `devf3` (input devices) and `devf04`, `devf05` and `devf05` (output devices).

I would suggest creating files `devf1`, `devf1` and `devf3`.